# Xcode project won't build, has no devices except Mac

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, git

I duplicated a project called Spartan App, and made the necessary changes to rename project to Wolverine App. The app is working great on my simulator and device so I pushed it up to Github for another developer to continue work on.

When the other developer opens the workspace, Xcode 6 doesn't seem to recognize it as an app. It still has the "Spartan App" as the target, and the only device shown is Mac. Neither of us know what's going on. Tried clearing and re-initializing the repo but that didn't help.

[image: See Image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Devices` in your `Wolverine App.xcodeproj` menu. Check that it's set to iPhone/iPad (whichever you're working on, or both). These files don't really play nice with git, unless you set them up to. See this link to try to make collaboration better for the future https://robots.thoughtbot.com/xcode-and-git-bridging-the-gap

Comment: Also check for device settings in your Info.plist

Comment: Not sure what to look for in the Info.plist. The only setting related to devices is 'Required device capabilities.' I have just one string item, 'armv7.' Another project has the same setting and is working just fine.